# Who is the Dottie number named after?

Tags: mathematics-social-history, numbers

I have learned about the [Dottie number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dottie_number), though I am unsure to whom it is attributed to and why it is named as so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dottie number is named in [Samuel Kaplan](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Kaplan2007-131105.pdf)'s (2007) paper after the women who discovered it.

> The Dottie number was the nickname among my graduate school friends
> for the unique real root of cos(x) = x.  The story goes that Dottie, a
> professor of French, noticed that whenever she put a number in the
> calculator and hit the cos button over and over again, the number on
> the screen always went to the same value, about 0.739085.

Comment: I definitely "discovered" it before 2007.